# append data to row in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need to append today's date to each row of a csv file.
First I append a field called "TodaysDate" to the headers row. that works fine, then I iterate through each row and want to append the date, but not all columns have data in each fields. I run into the problem illustrated below. the date being appended to the wrong column.

Is there a way I can pre-pend data to a row in csv?

```
Header1, Header2
data1, data2, 
data1, 
data1, data2, 

Header1, Header2, TodaysDate
data1, data2, today
data1, today
data1, data2, today
```

Comment: *pre-pend* means to add data *before* the other columns; you are talking about appending here.

Comment: Do your rows always end in a comma, in your real data file?

Comment: Retrieve first the max number of columns. Then for each row, count the number of element (comma separeted), if it is equal to the max, append your data, else, add the correct number of comma, then append the date.

Comment: Thanks that works well and is simple enough